# Code tour plugin

Tags: navigation

I was wondering if you know any helpful vim or neovim package/ way to show and explain your codebase to new people.

The best way I managed to find up until now is https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsls-contrib.codetour.

I think it's a problem many programmers bother with quite often, so I imagine someone did something to make it simpler :P

Comment: I suppose one could write a series of commands to display a message/popup, and then move to another part on input. Afaik nothing like this exists.